# Using SharpSNMP with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, snmp, sharp-snmp

I am starting to create an SNMP agent using SharpSNMP and VB.NET.

Could anyone let me know where I can find sample VB.NET code for this?

I have seen C# code but was unable to find any VB.NET code for this. Otherwise could someone show me a basic GET and SET using VB.NET and SharpSNMP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/tree/master/Samples/VB.NET

All VB.NET samples are there. Meanwhile, any VB.NET developer should learn C# IMHO.